# How can I install WTL 8.0 Project Wizards in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, wtl

I've downloaded the WTL 8.0 package and come to find the scripts to install App Wizards don't support VS 2010.

Does anyone know of updates scripts to support installation in VS 2010?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WTL 8.0 was released in june 2007 so couldn't possibly support VS 2010.

You may download the current **work in progress** WTL 8.1 AppWizard from http://wtl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wtl/trunk/wtl/Wizards/AppWiz.tar.gz?view=tar and the matching library files from [/include.tar.gz?view=tar](http://wtl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wtl/trunk/wtl/include/?view=tar).

Comment: I've double clicked on that js file and nothing happened .

Answer (score 8):

The AppWizard for VS2010 above has two small glitches (however they might deter people from using WTL with VS2010). These are very easy to fix:

**1) [Output Directory] and [Intermediate Directory] in new project properties are not followed by a backslash ('\').**

To fix:
file: .\AppWiz\Files\Scripts\1033\default.js

I have replaced:

```
            if(bDebug)
        {
            config.IntermediateDirectory = 'Debug';
            config.OutputDirectory = 'Debug';
            config.ATLMinimizesCRunTimeLibraryUsage = false;
        }
        else
        {
            config.IntermediateDirectory = 'Release\\';
            config.OutputDirectory = 'Release\\';
            config.ATLMinimizesCRunTimeLibraryUsage = true;
        }
```

with

```
        // Add generic configuration details
        config.IntermediateDirectory = '$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\\';
        config.OutputDirectory = '$(Configuration)\\';

        config.ATLMinimizesCRunTimeLibraryUsage = !bDebug;
```

**2) Some WTL headers are missing in newly created projects.**

The symbol WTL_USE_CPP_FILES seems to be missing when the template stdafx.h file is parsed, as a result a bunch of header files are not included in new projects.

Again in .\AppWiz\Files\Scripts\1033\default.js, I have added:

```
        // Add WTL_USE_CPP_FILES to all projects
    wizard.AddSymbol("WTL_USE_CPP_FILES", true)
```

just below line 41 (so that the lines are always included). This seems to do the trick.

I've never looked at VS appWizards before (or js for that matter), so I can't guarantee the workarounds are concrete. It seems pretty straighforward though & I've been using WTL with VS2010 with no problems since I've made those changes...

WTL is awesome btw - many thanks to the folks who still maintain it!

Cheers,
Yiannis

Comment: Thanks Yiannis, you saved my day (almost 1 year after you answered!).