# WTL 8.1 and Visual Studio 2010 Premium

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wtl

I have a weird problem with VS 2010 (Premium).

- just reinstalled it
- added the WTL library files
- installed the WTL wizard
- created a "dialog" project via the WTL wizard
- compiled and run the skeleton successfully
- added a button to the dialog
- compilation now fails complaining about undefined symbols (the button IDC_xxx)
- turned off pre-compiled headers
- cleaned solution, recompiled and run successfully
- added the "onClick" handler for the button (just by double clicking on the button, no code added)
- compilation fails complaining that `CUpdateUI` is not defined
- clean, reanalyze the solution, etc. doesn't solve the issue

If I manually insert `#include`'s (e.g. `atlframe.h` for `CUpdateUI`) I can make it work but this defeat the purpose of using VS2010!

What really annoys me is that I havent touched a single line of code, everything has been done through VS which, I hoped, should have cared for consistency!

Is it my fault? WTL fault? VS Fault? Any suggestion on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved thanks to the awesomeness of Stack Overflow!

It seems there's a bug in the WTL 8.1 Wizard. It doesn't define the WTL_USE_CPP symbol that is needed to make everything work correctly.

Head here:

[How can I install WTL 8.0 Project Wizards in VS 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260351/how-can-i-install-wtl-8-0-project-wizards-in-vs-2010)

and read Yiannis Spyridakis answer for the solution, if you have the same problem.